# Friends relationship data models in cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to have this relationship model in my cloud firestore models:
(https://www.codedodle.com/social-network-friends-database/)

Relationship Model

- user_one_id
- user_two_id
- status
- action_user_id

Status Codes
Code    Meaning

0   Pending

1   Accepted

2   Declined

3   Blocked

I'm not familiar with Firebase & No SQL a lot. But I see that I cannot make 'or' queries with cloud firestore. How can I convert this to Cloud Firestore Models?

For example in order to get friend list I have to do an or operation in my query:

Friends List

Retrieve all the users’ friends. Here user 1 is the logged in user.

```
SELECT * FROM `relationship`
  WHERE (`user_one_id` = 1 OR `user_two_id` = 1)
  AND `status` = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of storing the user IDs in two separate fields, you'll want to store them in a single array:

```
userIds: [1, 2]
```

With that field in the documents, you can then perform an [`array-contains` query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) to detect all documents where `1` is part of `userIds` with:

```
relationsRef.where('userIds', 'array-contains', 1);
```

And combined with your other condition:

```
relationsRef.where('userIds', 'array-contains', 1)
            .where('status', '=', 1)
```

If you're new to Firestore and NoSQL databases in general, I recommend reading [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and watching [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video). A few hours spent on those, will save you a multitude of that time going forward.